# DDD how to properly separate permissions and roles

Tags: typescript, security, permissions, authorization, domain-driven-design

Let's say I have an application which allows users to create, assign and edit tasks. The application is built to support multiple customer accounts. This application has various roles, but we'll focus on three and their permissions relevant to a specific action and resource (updating the text on a task) - admins (have permissions to update the text on all tasks across all accounts), account admins (have permissions to update the text on any task belonging to their accounts, but they could belong to multiple accounts) and account users (have permissions to update the text on a task only if that task is assigned to them).

The example is a bit contrived and role names are a bit over-generalized, but bear with me.

The goal here is to try to find a clean way to separate roles and permissions, but it seems the roles are inevitably tied to the permissions (see code below).

Perhaps the permission should just be `task:updateText`, but then how do I check the roles? Would I move my `switch (actor.type)` block in the domain model into a domain service and check there if the user is associated with an admin, account admin or account user on that particular account? Data can be cached, but account admins (and potentially other users) can be associated with multiple accounts which means pre-loading this data may require too much data in the context and could be problematic as this data is passed between services.

The ownership/assignment checks are done as part of the domain as they depend on the current state of the model. Not covered here, but a simple versioning mechanism is used to ensure a model does not change between the time it is retrieved and when updates have been applied. It seems policies might at least make this logic cleaner, but if I were to move this logic out into a policy I'm unsure how I would continue to guarantee that unless the policy and service method had a way to guarantee they shared the same version of the resource.

What are my options here? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
class TaskApplicationService {
  constructor(private taskRepository: TaskRepository) { }
  async updateText({ taskId, text, accountId, context }: { taskId: string, text: string, accountId?: string, context: Context }) {
    let actor: Actor;
    const userId = context.user.id;
    // permissions follow pattern resource:action:qualifier
    if (await hasPermission('task:updateText:all')) {
      actor = await anAdmin({ userId });
    } else if (await hasPermission('task:updateText:account')) {
      actor = await anAccountAdmin({ accountId, userId });
    } else if (await hasPermission('task.updateText:assigned')) {
      actor = await anAccountUser({ accountId, userId });
    } else {
      throw new Error('not authorized');
    }

    const task = await this.taskRepository.findOne({ taskId });
    task.updateText({ text, actor });
    await this.taskRepository.save(task);
    // return TaskMapper.toDto(task);
  }
}

class TaskDomainModel {
  private props: {
    text: string,
    accountId: string,
    assignedAccountUserId: string;
  };

  get text(): string {
    return this.props.text;
  }

  updateText({ text, actor }: { text: string, actor: Actor }) {
    switch (actor.type) {
      case ActorType.ADMIN:
        break;
      case ActorType.ACCOUNT_ADMIN:
        assert(this.props.accountId === actor.tenantId);
        break;
      case ActorType.ACCOUNT_USER:
        assert(this.props.accountId === actor.tenantId);
        assert(this.props.assignedAccountUserId === actor.tenantUserId);
        break;
      default:
        // note assertions and throwing errors are here for brevity,
        // but normally would use something similar to this:
        // https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/enterprise-typescript-nodejs/handling-errors-result-class/
        throw new Error('unknown actor type');
    }

    this.props.text = text;
  }
}

// supporting cast

interface User {
  id: string;
}

interface Context {
  user: User;
}

enum ActorType {
  ADMIN,
  ACCOUNT_ADMIN,
  ACCOUNT_USER
}

interface Admin {
  type: ActorType.ADMIN,
  userId: string
}

interface AccountAdmin {
  type: ActorType.ACCOUNT_ADMIN,
  tenantId: string,
  userId: string
}

interface AccountUser {
  type: ActorType.ACCOUNT_USER,
  tenantUserId: string,
  tenantId: string,
  userId: string
}

async function anAdmin({ userId }: { userId: string }): Promise<Admin> {
  // gets an admin
}

async function anAccountAdmin({ accountId, userId }: { accountId: string, userId: string }): Promise<AccountAdmin> {
  // gets an account admin
}

async function anAccountUser({ accountId, userId }: { accountId: string, userId: string }): Promise<AccountUser> {
  // gets an account user
}

async function hasPermission(permission: string) {
  // checks permissions in cache or calls to external service
}

type Actor = Admin | AccountAdmin | AccountUser;

interface TaskRepository {
  findOne({ taskId }: { taskId: string }): Promise<TaskModel>;
  save(task: TaskModel): Promise<TaskModel>;
}
```

Comment: Make your question more concise maybe got answer earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no need to couple roles to permissions this hard. Instead, you may have role class that contains list of generic permission like below.

```
class Permission {
    name: String;
}

class Role {
    name: String;
    permissions: Permission[];
}

class User {
    id: String;
    role: Role;
}
```

This way you can change what permissions roles actually have.

Another thing that concerns me is that your access checking logic is spilled all over the place which hurts code maintainability. Instead, you can extract it into single service. Here's a rough sketch.

```
class PermissionService {
    userHasRightToUpdateText = (task : Task, user: User) => {
        return (user.role.permissions.some(p => p.name == 'task:updateText:all')
            || (user.role.permissions.some(p => p.name == 'task:updateText:account') && task.accountId == user.id));
            //or whatever you auth logic is
    }
}

class TaskApplicationService {
    constructor(private taskRepository: TaskRepository,
        private userRepository: UserRepository,
        private permissionService : PermissionService) { }
    async updateText({ taskId, text, accountId, context }: { taskId: string, text: string, accountId?: string, context: Context }) {
      const userId = context.user.id;
      const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ userId });

      const task = await this.taskRepository.findOne({ taskId });

      if (this.permissionService.userHasRightToUpdateText(task, user)) {
        task.updateText({ text });
        await this.taskRepository.save(task);
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('not authorized');
      }
      // return TaskMapper.toDto(task);
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking of using policies in this way and it does solve my transactional and versioning concerns although I'd be interested in how .NET does things like this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-handler-for-multiple-requirements) and if it can still offer the same guarantees. Extracting the logic into a policy is the easy part for me. The hard part is determining what type of user I'm dealing with. I have three types of users in my example - the admin user that can update the text on any task...

Comment: the account admin that can update the text only for tasks under their accounts and then the account user that can update only tasks in their account and for which they have been assigned. In my model, and I'm unsure if this is the correct approach, the account user entity (not the user) is the one which would be assigned to the task. Maybe I should be using the `userId` for the assignment, but then if I remove that user from the account user role (but they are still in other roles) how do I know which entities they are related to in the capacity of an account user / what I need to clean up?

Comment: For clarity - the assignment in my current approach would be `task.accountUserId = accountUser.id`.

Comment: the idea behind my example is that you don't need to figure out which user you are dealing with. In `PermissionsService` it is enough to be able to tell which permission does user have and check for additional constraints like whether task belongs to the user in question. User role in the example is merely the container for permissions.